# How to create desktop application for running perl script

Tags: perl

I just want to create desktop application(User Interface) for running a custom perl script.

Please can anyone let me know how to create or any available docs.I have searched google but couldn't find anything in specific.

Thanks

Comment: Hello. You look like you're a newcomer to stack overflow. Your questions is extremely broad, and so it's not possible to meaningfully answer.  Please check out: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It is possible to run command line commands with system("my command") and, according to my search, you can launch a perl script from the command line with perl my_perl_script.

Comment: Your question essentially boils down to "Recommend me a GUI library", and software recommendation questions are off-topic for Stackoverflow. You might have better luck on a site like Perl Monks (although do search first as this is quite a common question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with TK and Win32::GUI. These are the perl USER INTERFACE Support modules.